# How to handle company rebrand/rename in Developer Story?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

The company I’m working at has changed its name, logo and website. How should I reflect this in my developer story?

Is it possible to add this information to the company page? (Doesn’t seem so.) Should I add another entry in the story (and make it look like I changed jobs)?

Should I keep only the old company info on my story, or only the new info, for the whole duration of the job?

Comment: [A quite relevant post from another stack exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/listing-a-renamed-company-on-a-resume-or-in-a-cover-letter)

Comment: @Draken Yeah, and the best answer to that post recommends listing both names… which I don’t think I can do in Developer Story. :-(

Comment: You can edit the name of the company to "XYZ Corporation (formerly ABC, Inc)", and replace the old logo with the new one. Wouldn't it suffice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would keep only the new info.

The old name/brand is no longer relevant, the company has a **new name**. For most purposes, the old entity doesn't really exist anymore.

As more time passes, anyone who knows about that company would know it by this new name, not the old one.

And making it seems you changed jobs is less accurate, and would not necessarily reflect well on you.

Comment: unless the old company was cool and the rebrand is terrible :)

Comment: @Vorsprung in which case you swiftly move to a new company with a current cool brand, and only list the old brand in your developer story, of course.

Comment: The company has its own on Developer Story, but it doesn’t seem possible to actually rename it, is it? So do you think I should just edit my own story and in doing so create a new company entry with the new name? (I’m currently the only person with this company on here, so it might not matter much.)

Comment: @Chortos-2 AFAIK "companies" are just items inside your developer story, and not really related to other stories. E.g. I can create edit my developer story and add that I worked in Complete Payment Systems as you did, the autocomplete will offer me the name, URL, logo (which I can edit completely or partially or leave as it was), and later clicking on the company name in my profile will show me, and not you. So you just edit the story item with the new company name, and the "page" for the old company will be no more.