# How to correct employer's name (developer story)

Tags: support, developer-story, display-names, companies-page, spelling

My company's name starts with a capital *D* and not with a *d*: 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/361319/digitec-galaxus-ag?storyType=1

How can we correct this error?

I found the following thread, but it doesn't really apply to me because my company did not have a rebranding: *[How to handle company rebrand/rename in Developer Story?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374463/how-to-handle-company-rebrand-rename-in-developer-story)*

I also found this one which seems to be resolved by manually editing the company through a user with elevated privileges: *[Jobs developer story shows incorrect company logo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339128/jobs-developer-story-shows-incorrect-company-logo)*

The correct name can be seen on our official website:
https://www.digitec.ch/en/wiki/528 or on the company's Stack Overflow Jobs page: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/digitec-galaxus-ag

I'd like follow up on the discussion in the comments. We operate the two largest e-commerce platforms in Switzerland (digitec.ch and galaxus.ch). digitec is spelled with a lower d if it is referred to without mentioning its sibling Galaxus. This is due to historical reasons. digitec was our first platform and the logo is a lower d. Therefore, when Galaxus was brought to life it wouldn't have been smart to rebrand digitec. This is consistent across all our branding. You can see an example of that in action [here](https://www.digitec.ch/en/wiki/528):
[image]

However, the company is still called Digitec Galaxus AG.

Comment: [It is also on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitec_Galaxus). Companies often don't know how to spell their own name and may spell it in three different ways on the same page on their website. Some are confused by the [stylised spelling in a logo](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (which is *not* the same as the actual spelling).

Comment: But there is *"digitec connect"* in the left panel on the referenced company page (all other items have (inconsistent) varying degrees of capitalisation - unless "Help Centre" can be considered a proper noun).

Comment: On the main page, *https://www.digitec.ch/*, on the right is *"digitec Deal of the day"* (in the German version it is *"digitec Tagesangebot"* - also *"digitec Live"* on that page).

Comment: I hadn't looked at the pages when I wrote the first comment.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Agreed. If something is related to digitec only (which provides an electornics assortment, then it is spelled with a lower d. At some point we started to sell all sorts of things. Back then Galaxus (galaxus.ch) was born and the company was rebranded to "Digitec Galaxus AG". "digitec connect" is a mobile phone subscription sold on digitec, that is why it has a lower d. But the company's name is still "Digitec Galaxus AG" as you will find on all legal papers and other resources such as the SO Jobs page, wikipedia, media, etc.